How to test a pybuilder custom plugin locally?
I have several pybuilder projects working. And I want to go a step further ... build my own pybuilder plugin.
There are numerous examples. Even with a description how to publish a plugin to pypi.
But before I take this step, I want to be sure that it works.
So the big question is ... how do I locally install the custom plugin to be picked up by pybuilder AND is it possible to debug the code?
Firstly I created/build a wheel distribution of the custom plugin with pybuilder.
Then in my example pybuilder project, where I want to use the plugin,

I activated the virtual environment,
pip installed the custom plugin wheel
added the plugin to the build.py with the use_plugin line
ran " pyb <task>"

result is "Build FAILED - No such task..."
